# Where can I find the key to the top roof of the College of Winterhold?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Where can I find the key to the top floor (roof) of the College of Winterhold?

My game has glitched and Mirabelle Ervine seems to be up there. I think it was due to a dragon landing in the court yard directly after I got the mission.

Comment: Could you describe exactly where you're talking about? Both the Hall of Attainment and Hall of Countenance have exits to the roof at the top of the stairwells -- but maybe that's not what you mean?

Comment: do you mean the top from the Archmage's quarters?

Comment: sorry, yeah im talking about the top of the archmages quarters, any help would be amazing

Comment: Did you complete all the Winterhold College quests? I believe You need to become Arch-Mage.

Answer (score 1):

Ben,

You will get the key when you become Arch-Mage of the college.

I am not sure where you are in the quest line, so don't know if you need Mirabelle to progress in the quest line. I hope not.

Part of the quest line to become an Arch-Mage does require talking to Mirabelle. See: http://supremegamer.hubpages.com/hub/skyrim-defeating-morokei.

Answer (score 0):

If Mirabelle is stuck up there (not leaving that position at any time of the day) and you're playing on PC, you could cheat and noclip up there to get the quest resolved.

http://www.gamefront.com/skyrim-pc-console-commands/

Comment: Forget noclip.  Just do `prid 0001C1B9 <ENTER> moveto player`.  Why go to her when you can just make her come to you?